# powershell getting the remote directory name and filename to put in destination filename

Tags: file, powershell, filesystems, powershell-2.0

I have this bit of powershell script but i can't get the $DirectoryName to behave as expected.

```
1,2,3 |
foreach { 
    $count = $_; 
    $x = gci -Path \\myserver-web$count\d$\IISLogs\ -include *.log -recurse

    $x | Copy-Item -Destination D:\ServerLogsAndBackups\IIS\w$count\$_.DirectoryName_$_.Name -whatIf
}
```

When I run this though I get

What if: Performing operation "Copy File" on Target "Item: \myserver-web1\d$\IISLogs\W3SVC1165836668\ex101224.log Destination: D:\ServerLogsAndBackups\IIS\w1\1.DirectoryName_1.Name".

What I want it to be is

```
W3SVC1165836668_ex101206.log
```

where my directory structure is like:

```
\\myserver-web1\d$\IISLogs\W3SVC1165836668
\\myserver-web1\d$\IISLogs\W3SVC1165837451
\\myserver-web1\d$\IISLogs\W3SVC1165836966
\\myserver-web1\d$\IISLogs\W3SVC1165812365
```

with files called ex101206.log in each folder

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1,2,3 |
foreach { 
    $count = $_;
    gci -Path \\myserver-web$count\d$\IISLogs\ -include *.log -recurse | % { $dirName = $_.directoryname.Substring($_.directoryname.LastIndexOf("\")+1); $logname = $_.Name; $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $("D:\ServerLogsAndBackups\IIS\w"+$count+"\"+$dirname+"_"+$logName) -whatif }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate the `$_.Directoryname_$_.Name` part. Like so,

```
$x | Copy-Item -Destination $(D:\ServerLogsAndBackups\IIS\w$count\$_.DirectoryName_$_.Name) -whatIf
```

Comment: Half way there with: $x | ForEach-Object {
  Copy-Item $x -Destination $("D:\ServerLogsAndBackups\IIS\w"+$count+"\"+$_.Directoryname+"_"+$_.Name) -whatIf
 } however it's claiming my destination to be like.. D:\ServerLogsAndBackups\IIS\w1\myserver-web1\d$\IISLogs\W3SVC1135081669_ex110330.log